# What does it mean " There exists an element in V" ??

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, terminology

I'm studying linear algebra and analysis. I'm not a English user so that some sentences are confusing to me:

> "There exists an element in $V$ (vector space) denoted by $0$ such that $x+0=x$ for each $x$ in $V$"

What does it mean that "There exists an element in $V$"?

Does it mean that there exists only one element in $V$? Because "an" is one, right?

A similar problem is in analysis too.

> "Every infinite subset of $K$ has a limit point in $K$"

Does it mean that every infinite subset of $K$ has only one limit point in $K$?

Comment: the simple meaning of the English is that there exists at least one, but perhaps you can prove that it's unique

Comment: And for $0$ it's relatively easy to proove. Suppose there are 2, $0_1$ and $0_2$, then $0_1=0_1+0_2=0_2$.

Comment: I’d like to make a linguistic comment not covered by any of the others here. It’s true that “an” originates from the word “one”, but it is *never* a counting number, and is not used for saying “one rather than any other number”. It is just a signal that the noun that it modifies is singular. Not always necessary, but if I say “a sheep” you know that it should take a singular verb, while “sheep” standing alone could be singular or plural. Much more generally, remember that English is an Indo-European language, and these usually make a careful distinction between singular and plural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is a bit confusing to non-English speakers.  On the one hand, the word "an" is an indefinite article indicating there is at least one, but possibly more.  On the other hand, when we refer to "an element $\ldots$ denoted by $0$," we're implying that there is only one such element (because we're naming it).

This is actually foreshadowing.  We are saying that there is at least one such element but it is very easy to prove (by considering $0_1+0_2$ if there were two such elements) that the element must be unique.

The second sentence unambiguously says merely that there is at least one limit point.

Comment: thank you very much for answering.  but why does not the second sentence say that there is only one limit point, but at least one limit point ?   my grammar book says a/an mean one.

Comment: Because the use of the term "a" means that there is one, but doesn't exclude the possibility that there also are others.  To assert that an object is unique, one would ordinarily use the definite article "the."  "Please put my car in a garage next to my house" asks you to pick one of possibly many garages next to my house. "Please put my car in the garage next to my house" asserts that there is only one garage next to my house and asks you to put my car there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a misconception even for native English speakers. We say 'there is' to mean one *or* many. For instance, if you were to ask if there is any bread in the kitchen, I might answer, "There is bread." But this could mean a single slice or many. We rely on context to determine if the object is unique or if there are many.

Mathematically, we always mean the same thing when we say 'there exists.' We only mean at least one, because then it does exist! This could mean there are many such 'objects' or a unique one. If the object is unique, we would mathematically say 'there exists a unique.' Note that we will also say 'there exists' even when the object is unique - this is something we will show later.

In your example, we say 'there exists an element $0$ with....' This $0$ object turns out to be unique, but we prove later because we do not need to define it to be unique. Notice by defining that there is at least one object with the property you described will actually imply it to be unique. This is not true with all definitions. For example, I will say an integer $n$ is a square if it can be written as $n=k^2$ for some $k$. Note that when such a $k$ exists, it is never unique because $-k$ works as well, e.g. $4=2^2=(-2)^2$. Sometimes objects you define do not exist, sometimes they are unique, other times there are a few, other times infinitely many. It all depends on the properties!

Comment: thank you very much.  but I can't still clearly understand the meaning.  if "there exists a element~" means at least one,  what is the difference between "there exist elements~" and  "there exists a element~" ?

Comment: The use of the plural generally implies more than one, but in context it's possible that the phrase "there exist elements" doesn't rule out the possibility that what appear to be multiple elements are actually equal to (or equivalent to) one another.  The phrase "there exists an element" merely asserts there is at least one such element.

Comment: @juso I second Robert Shore's excellent response to your question. Indeed, mathematicians probably should be more careful with their language. The reason for the 'sloppiness' is that their reader is often assumed to be able to distinguish the difference by context - but this is not always the case. When in doubt ask! The good thing is that with a bit of experience, you too will be able to always distinguish the difference just as easily!